# Atualizando dados de gráficos já instanciados

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Estou utilizando o [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts) e estou precisando atualizar um mapa que ja está instanciado como um mapa valido, na verdade quero quando clicar no botão atualizar os dados de dentro de um mapa.

Hoje estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
var dataGraf = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(parsVal);
var chart = document.getElementById('curve_chart');
chart.draw(dataGraf);
```

Porém nada acontece. Para eu instanciar meu mapa utilizei os seguintes comandos:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(parsVal);
  var options = {
    title: 'Membros x Visitantes',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };
 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
 chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Como posso fazer para atualizar, justamente quando clico no botão. Lembrando que meu `dataGraf` tem meu array com os novos valores.

Fiz um [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh5Lk3xj/) para exemplificar meu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Quando clicar no botão você redesenha o gráfico inteiro.

```
$("#botaoAtualizar").click(function(){
    redrawChart();
});
```

Usa a função que você já fez passando os novos dados.

```
function drawChart() {

  var dataGraf = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(parsVal);

  var options = {
    title: 'Membros x Visitantes',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
 chart.draw(dataGraf, options);

}
```